# meaning of Warnung: Symbol 'AllocateHWnd' wird abgelehnt

Tags: build-automation, compiler-warnings, suppress-warnings, c++builder-6, deprecation-warning

When building a BCB6 project on the command line via `MAKE Version 5.2` running `Borland C++ 5.6.4` (seemingly including a run of `Borland Delphi Version 14.0`), I'm getting these warnings:

```
syncmeth.pas(57) Warnung: Symbol 'AllocateHWnd' wird abgelehnt

syncmeth.pas(62) Warnung: Symbol 'DeallocateHWnd' wird abgelehnt
```

Several web searches for the German phrase didn't provide any useful results. Then I tried to translate it, starting with things like

> Warning: symbol 'AllocateHWnd' [is/was] denied

with just as little success. Finally I tried without the verb

> warning symbol 'AllocateHWnd'

and found something promising: a lot of search results matching the pattern

> Symbol '<whatever>' is deprecated.

But the German *abgelehnt* means *denied* and definitely **not** *deprecated* (which means *veraltet* as usually translated in the software development domain).

Can anybody **confirm that this is only a translation error**, so that I can just ignore the warnings (of course aware what deprecated means)?

Comment: Maybe from the area where names longer than 8 letters were truncated (and case insensitive)? ALLOCATE might have been reserved. If I am right, I take a day off.

Comment: @JoopEggen This I doubt. Delphi and Borland C++ both allow long identifiers since they exist. And it's the same for `DeallocateHWnd`. I'm directly using these functions, and I had never issues with them. The problem in the given case is that I'm using a Delphi source file in a C++Builder project *and* in a Delphi project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Google search of that exact German phrasing reveals the following discussions:

[Strange Warning in D6 (need some help)](http://www.delphigroups.info/2/2f/507011.html)

[AllocateHWnd - Compiler-Warnung?](http://de.comp.lang.delphi.misc.narkive.com/L2hzRFZr/allocatehwnd-compiler-warnung) ([English translation](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=de&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fde.comp.lang.delphi.misc.narkive.com%2FL2hzRFZr%2Fallocatehwnd-compiler-warnung&act=url))

Despite the German phrase "wird abgelehnt" translating as "is denied" or "is rejected" in the traditional sense, the warning messages in question actually *DO* mean **deprecated** in this situation.

The `AllocateHWnd()` and `DeallocateHWnd()` functions originally resided in the VCL's `Forms` unit.  Their implementation was moved to the RTL's `Classes` unit in Delphi/C++Builder 6 (to support the CLX framework in Kylix), and the existing functions in the `Forms` unit were marked as `deprecated` (they were finally removed from the `Forms` unit in Delphi/C++Builder 2009).

So, the only way you can be getting those warnings in your project is if your `syncmeth.pas` file is calling the deprecated functions in the `Forms` unit instead of calling the newer functions in the `Classes` unit.

Comment: I see, I'll have a closer look at it soon, thanks a lot. There is a detail I remember only now: I first wrote and tested the solution with Lazarus, then "ported it back" to D4, then used it also in BCB6. Maybe VCL and LCL are different here...

Comment: Whatsoever, your explanation is completely plausible. ...and sufficient ;)